# oracle Level column to postgres conversion

Tags: postgresql

I have an oracle query to change it into postgres

```
SELECT cast(to_char(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -6),'MM'),LEVEL - 1),'MMYYYY') as number) monthid,
to_char (ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -6),'MM'), LEVEL - 1),'MON-YYYY') monthdesc
From dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= MONTHS_ BETWEEN (SYSDATE, ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -6)) + 1;
```

I tried with CTE and generate_series, but stuck somewhere to get result set

```
---------------------
MONTHID     MONTHDESC 
---------------------
172022      JUL-2022 
82022       AUG-2022 
92022       SEP-2022 
102022      OCT-2022 
112022      NOV-2022 
122022      DEC-2022 
12023       JAN-2023
```

Comment: I don't understand how `172022` is generated through `to_char(..., 'MMYYYY')` - there is no month 17 - should the first value be `072022`?

Comment: *I tried with CTE and generate_series* - but there's no any Postgres code or error message in the question. Should we guess?

Answer (score 0):

This will generate a list of the last six months:

```
select to_char(g.dt, 'mmyyyy') as monthid,
       to_char(g.dt, 'MON-yyyy') as monthdesc
from generate_series(date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '6 month', 
                     date_trunc('month', current_date), interval '1 month') as g(dt)
```

However this will return `072022` for July 2022, not `172022` as in your sample data.

Comment: Great work thanks a lot for kind help